# How can set flux slider effects to use on ul li tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can we set flux slider effects on ul li tags?

For example we have a html like this:

```
<ul class="flux">

<li><img src="images/img1.jpg"/></li>

<li><img src="images/img2.jpg"/><</li>

<li><img src="images/img3.jpg"/></li>

</ul>
```

You can take a look at flux slider from http://www.joelambert.co.uk/flux/

Thanks for helps.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't use the HTML structure the [Documentation](https://github.com/joelambert/Flux-Slider#usage) recommends to use?

Comment: Where is your code? Did you try something?

Comment: @blex  Actually I want to use flux effects on codrops google grid http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/03/21/google-grid-gallery/. This grid using ul li tags for sliding.